# quartz core generating loads of VM: UILabel(CA Layer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uilabel, quartz-core

I have an app which drags messages dynamically from server, as scrolling to top, old messages will be retrieved and display on the screen like other messaging apps, but my app keeps generating UIlabel, even though no more old messages presents after all the old messages are retrieved, the UIlabel will still be generated if the list is being scrolled, and the source is from QuartzCore, responsible caller is CA::Render::Shemem::new_shmem(unsigned long).

Can anyone help me, I'm quite new at developing ios, and im using objective-C, the memory issue cause my app crashed on every version of iphones as the UILabel stacks and seems like it will never release unless I switched to other chatrooms. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's difficult to help you because you haven't show us the code that creates the UILabels. Edit your question to include that.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm not sure which part of the code I should post, as I don't know what code is generating that issue, the excessive UILabels generated is shown in the profile recordings when I'm testing why the app crashed when it's scrolled to a certain length, also if the chat history is too long, it will not be able to show all old messages, how can I check which code is responsible to the UILabel generated as it only says quartzCore as the responsible library... many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are adding labels to a scroll view. Change your app to use a table view or a collection view to display messages. These classes automatically remove and reuse cells that are scrolled off the screen.

Comment: I launched the app using profile->Allocation Sumary, and i spectate the increasing memory usage, it is mostly used in VM: CoreAnimation, as all the files and data such as images and videos didnt stack, so what scenarios would u suspect that causes the failure of memory release? many thanks